# Space appears between divs

Tags: css, html, space

Here is page code and you will find image of the code below it:

```
<body style="color: #25670c; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0; font-family : Times New Roman; font-size : 16px; text-align: center;">

<div style="width:985px; margin:0 auto; background-color:#d6d6a4;">
<div style="height: 96px; width: 985px;"><a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Digi-Spot">
    <img border="0" src="http://www.gvcdigital.co.uk/images/graphic/header.png" width="985" height="96" alt="header" title="DigiSpot eBay store" /></a></div>
<div style="height: 41px; width: 985px;">
    <img border="0" src="http://www.gvcdigital.co.uk/images/graphic/meniu.png" alt="DigiSpot meniu" width="985" height="41" usemap="#mapas" />

<map name="mapas">
  <area shape="rect" coords="56,0,0,41" href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Digi-Spot" alt="DigiSpot eBay store home" title="DigiSpot eBay store home">
  <area shape="rect" coords="539,0,400,41" href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Digi-Spot/About-us.html" alt="About Digispot" title="About DigiSpot">
  <area shape="rect" coords="699,0,539,41" href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Digi-Spot/Delivery.html" alt="Delivery information" title="Delivery information">
  <area shape="rect" coords="845,0,699,41" href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Digi-Spot/Returns.html" alt="Returns information" title="Returns information">
    <area shape="rect" coords="985,0,845,41" href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Digi-Spot/Contacts.html" alt="Contacts information" title="Contacts information">
</map> </div>

  <div style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="float:left; width: 661px; text-align: center;">
        <img border="0" src="http://www.gvcdigital.co.uk/images/graphic/description.png" width="232" height="81" title="Product description"><br /><p style="text-align: left; margin-left: 10;">[[Description]]</p></div>
    <div style="float:left; width: 324px; text-align: center;">
        <div style="color: #ffffff; background-color:#6b8861; font-size : 18px;" title="Product title">[[Title]]</div>
        <div style="border:1px dotted #6b8861; text-align:center; width: 324px; background-color:#ffffff;" title="Product picture">[[Picture1]]</div>
        <div style="width: 324px; color: #000000; font-size : 18px;" title="In stock: [[QtyToList]]">In stock: <b>[[QtyToList]]</b></div>
        <div style="width: 324px; color: #801010; font-size : 35px;" title="Product Price">Price: [[BuyItNowPrice]]</div>
    </div>
</div>


<div style="clear: both; text-align: center; width:200px; margin: 0 auto; background-color:#58794c; color: #ffffff; font-size : 28px; border-top:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;">Postage</div>
<div style="width:985px; margin: 0 auto; background-color:#58794c; color: #efda5d; border-bottom:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;"><p style="text-align: left; margin-left: 10;">Available shipping type/It's price/Additional cost for this product:<br />[[ShippingService1]]/[[ShippingServiceCost1]]/[[ShippingServiceAdditionalCost1]]<br />[[ShippingService2]]/[[ShippingServiceCost2]]/[[ShippingServiceAdditionalCost2]]<br />[[ShippingService3]]/[[ShippingServiceCost3]]/[[ShippingServiceAdditionalCost3]]<br />[[ShippingService4]]/[[ShippingServiceCost4]]/[[ShippingServiceAdditionalCost4]]<br />More information about products delivery you will find by clicking <a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Digi-Spot/Delivery.html">here</a>.</p></div>
<br />
<div style="text-align: center; width:200px; background-color:#558b40; color: #ffffff; font-size : 28px; border-top:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;">Return</div>
<div style="width:985px; margin: 0 auto; background-color:#558b40; color: #efda5d; border-bottom:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;"><p style="text-align: left; margin-left: 10;">Product must be returned within [[ReturnWithin]] to this adress <b>[[ReturnAddress]]</b>. For return shipping pays <b>[[ReturnShipPaid]]</b>.<br /> More information about returning products you will find by clicking <a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Digi-Spot/Returns.html">here</a>.</p></div>
<br />
<div style="text-align: center; width:200px; margin: 0 0 0 0; background-color:#66ac4a; color: #ffffff; font-size : 28px; border-top:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;">Payment</div>
<div style="width:985px; margin: 0 auto; background-color:#66ac4a; color: #efda5d; border-bottom:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;"><p style="text-align: left; margin-left: 10;">Product price is <b>[[FixedPrice]]</b><br />Additional payment instructions for this product: [[PaymentInstructions]]</p></div>

<div style="text-align: center; width:985px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <img border="0" src="http://www.gvcdigital.co.uk/images/graphic/buttom.png" width="524" height="42" title="DigiSpot - Supplier of Electrical and Related Products at Low Price"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is what it looks like (marked probematic zones in red):
[image]

Whats is the problem here? I know it's something "small" but, I cant find the problem :s
This problem only appears in Chrome browser.

Comment: Is all of your CSS inline???

Comment: Please don't do that. That's horrendous for maintainability, readability, etc. Use a stylesheet.

Comment: I can't, this template is for ebay store, and in here it's imposible to define code out of body scope...

Comment: what browser are you using when this happens? what mode are you running in?

Comment: Now when I checked I noticed that only in "Chrome" its displayed wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `"margin-top:0"` to the `<p>` tags, as the browser will add a default top margin otherwise and since they are inline elements inside a block level div they are forcing the margin outside of the containing div's.

Answer (score 1):

the space occur as you have applied margin so just Remove `margin: 10;`

Comment: After removing it nothing changes. If you mean `margin-left: 10px;`.

Answer (score 0):

Inline style...I feel the pain! :P

OK your issue is the **p tag**:

```
<p style="text-align: left;">
Available shipping type/It's price/Additional cost for this product:
```

Make the fix by adding a margin there like this:

```
<p style="text-align: left; margin: 0px;">
```

Happy Coding :)